# Change cell color of cell if within 3 days of cell date

Tags: excel, date, formatting, conditional-statements

I am attempting to make a cheat-sheet for paperwork that needs to be submitted at a specific date. Cell A8 is the given date; cells B8-F8 have formulas to generate dates based on A8's given date. I want cells B18-F8 to turn red 3 days before the generated dates, and stay that way until the due date passes (for now).

I have tried: =$FD8<=FD8 - (3) with every variation of "<,>,<="

Most solutions me to use "TODAY()" but I specifically want it to go off of the given date.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: How can FD8 be less than or equal to itself - 3

Comment: TODAY() returns a number, you can simply substract 3 to get 3 days earlier: `=TODAY()-3`

Answer (score 0):

It would be most convenient to use another set of cells to generate the B8-F8 dates and to substract three days. For example, B9-F9. Then you can use conditional formatting to format B8-F8 based on the B9-F9 values.

To substract days you can generate a VBA code that creates a custom function.

```
Function myDateAdd(interval, howmany, adate)
myDateAdd = DateAdd(interval, howmany, adate)
End Function
```

Or write a more elaborate formula

```
=IF(
DAY(B8)>3,
DATE(YEAR(B8),MONTH(B8),DAY(B8)-3),
DATE(YEAR(B8),MONTH(B8)-1,(DAY(B8)-31)*-1)
)
```

You still need to write something extra to verify that the B8 date has 31 (or 30 or 28) days. Combine IF() and ISDATE() multiple times to achieve this.